# Error al comparar fechas con la función gregoriantojd

Tags: php

Sigo con mis problemas de fechas. Estoy comparando fechas con la función `gregoriantojd` pero no logro entender por qué me lanza un error llamado `parse error syntaxis error`.

Este es mi código:

```
function compararFechas($fecha_pago, $fecha_vence){

  $valoresfecha_pago = $fecha_pago;
  $valoresfecha_vence = $fecha_vence;

  $diafecha_pago    = $valoresfecha_pago[0];  
  $mesfecha_pago    = $valoresfecha_pago[1];  
  $anyofecha_pago   = $valoresfecha_pago[2]; 

  $diafecha_vence   = $valoresfecha_vence[0];  
  $mesfecha_vence   = $valoresfecha_vence[1];  
  $anyofecha_vence  = $valoresfecha_vence[2];



$diasfecha_pago = gregoriantojd($mesfecha_pago, $diafecha_pago, $anyofecha_pago);  
  $diasfecha_vence = gregoriantojd($mesfecha_vence, $diafecha_vence, $anyofecha_vence);     

  return   $diasfecha_vence - $diasfecha_pago;

}

$fecha_vence = "28-02-2016";
$hoy = date("d-m-Y");

echo compararFechas ($hoy,$fecha_vence);
```

Comment: Ignoro PHP pero, al hacer `$valoresfecha_vence[2]` que viene de un string `$fecha_vence = "28-02-2016"` no obtienes `-`?, tal vez a eso se deba el error de parseo. A menos que esté hablando cosas sin sentido y en ese caso ["I have no idea what I'm talking about"](http://www.leparcorama.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/I-have-no-idea-what-im-talking-about.gif)

Comment: Si pudieras incorporar toda la línea de error para ver en qué línea se produce sería ideal.

Comment: El problema es el mismo que en las preguntas anteriores: estás usando strings donde deberías estar usando fechas o un array. Te recomendaría que aprendieses a _debuggear_ las aplicaciones (incluso si es de una forma simple escribiendo valores por pantalla). Es una habilidad muy útil y te ayudará a ahorrar tiempo y quebraderos de cabeza

Comment: Este es el error completo Warning: gregoriantojd() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given on line 19 y en la linea 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincido con el comentario de Álvaro Montoro solo que lo haría mas fácil y agregaría un `explode()`a las variables de la función para eliminar los guiones de hecho esa debió ser la idea original de este script ya que luego las variables `$valoresfecha_XXX[]`son array que toman el día , el mes y el año. Yo solo corregiría las siguientes líneas:

En vez de esto

```
$valoresfecha_pago = $fecha_pago;
$valoresfecha_vence = $fecha_vence;
```

pondría esto:

```
$valoresfecha_pago = explode("-", $fecha_pago);   
$valoresfecha_vence = explode("-", $fecha_vence);
```

Lo replique y funciono bien al igual que el ejemplo de Álvaro Montoro. 
Nos avisas si te sirve.

Comment: Si, funciona perfecto gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Como bien indica César en su comentario, el problema está aquí:

```
$diafecha_pago    = $valoresfecha_pago[0];  
$mesfecha_pago    = $valoresfecha_pago[1];  
$anyofecha_pago   = $valoresfecha_pago[2]; 

$diafecha_vence   = $valoresfecha_vence[0];  
$mesfecha_vence   = $valoresfecha_vence[1];  
$anyofecha_vence  = $valoresfecha_vence[2];
```

porque `$valoresfecha_pago` y `$valoresfecha_vence` son cadenas de texto, por lo que cuando haces `$valoresfecha_vence[X]` no obtienes lo que día, mes y año como esperas, si no un valor diferente: el primer, segundo y tercer carácter de la cadena.

Podría llegar a funcionar si la cadena tuviera un formato diferente, pero el tercer carácter de la cadena no es numérico sino un guión (`-`) y eso hace que obtengas el mensaje de error: `Warning: gregoriantojd() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given on line 19`, porque se espera un número pero mandas una cadena.

Deberías convertir esas variables a fechas en lugar de cadenas y obtener los valores de otra manera. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
function compararFechas($fecha_pago, $fecha_vence){

  $fecha1 = date_create($fecha_pago);
  $fecha2 = date_create($fecha_vence);

  $diafecha_pago    = date_format($fecha1, "d");  
  $mesfecha_pago    = date_format($fecha1, "m");  
  $anyofecha_pago   = date_format($fecha1, "Y");  

  $diafecha_vence   = date_format($fecha2, "d");  
  $mesfecha_vence   = date_format($fecha2, "m");  
  $anyofecha_vence  = date_format($fecha2, "Y");  


  $diasfecha_pago = gregoriantojd($mesfecha_pago, $diafecha_pago, $anyofecha_pago);  
  $diasfecha_vence = gregoriantojd($mesfecha_vence, $diafecha_vence, $anyofecha_vence);     

  return   $diasfecha_vence - $diasfecha_pago;

}

$fecha_vence = "28-02-2016";
$hoy = date("d-m-Y");

echo compararFechas ($hoy,$fecha_vence) ;
```

Comment: Lo hice así y me aparece un error . fatal Error of type date Time as array

Comment: @AndresMorgado Cometí un fallo tipográfico en el nombre de las variables. Lo he corregido y he añadido el código completo que ahora sí funciona

Answer (score 0):

El error te aparece por que te falta ; despues de declarar las variables

```
 $valoresfecha_pago = $fecha_pago
 $valoresfecha_vence = $fecha_vence
```

arregla eso y te bota otro error que tiene que ver con los tipos de datos que envias al metodo gregoriantojd, ademas el formato de gregriantojd es el siguiente:

```
gregoriantojd ( int $month , int $day , int $year );
```

estas enviando primero el dia. Revisa eso.

Comment: No ya lo había visto y lo arregle. Ahora me da Warning gregoriantojd() expets